# How to display the Contact phone and contact email id in a custom object

Tags: lookup

I have a custom object 'Custom case'. I have selected a contact in the field 'contact name' using a lookup relationship. When the user selects a contact in that field corresponding that particular contact's phone number and email id should be displayed in the fields 'contact email and contact phone'..

how to accomplish this?

Thanks,
Savitha C

Comment: do you want it implement through custom way i mean by using vfpages or standard way ..

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the Contact Email and Contact Phone fields [formulas](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Formulas). You can then reference them through something like:

```
Contact__r.Email
```

---

```
Contact__r.Phone
```

You can find all [Contact fields](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm) in the documentation.